# Closed Form for the Integral: $\int_0^1 t^n\log\Gamma(t+a)dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, polygamma

I am wondering if someone could tell me whether or not the following integral has a closed form representation:

$$\int_0^1 t^n\log\Gamma(t+a)dt$$

In Srivastava's and Choi's wonderful book *Zeta and q-Zeta Functions and Associated Series and Integrals*, they give a closed form for the following Digamma integral:

$$\int_0^1 t^n\psi(t)dt$$

and the also list specific cases for the integral I am searching for, but not the general case.

The formulae for the integrals containing $n>2$ become extremely complex, which makes me wonder whether a closed form exists but I was hoping someone could settle this question for me.

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: The 1998 paper by Adamchik ["Polygamma functions of negative order"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798001927) may interest you. The answer is given in function of $\psi^{(-n)}(t)$ (integrals of polygamma or "Negapolygamma" in Adamchik 'parlance'). An example using [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28t%5E1*ln%28gamma%28t%2BPI%29%29%2Ct%3D0..1%29). Another [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305079.pdf) by Espinosa and Moll.

Comment: Raymond:  Thank you so much for the references, I will take a look!

Comment: Glad it interested you @FofX. Note that Gosper's 'negapolygamma' is in fact defined by $$\psi^{(-n-2)}=(z):=\frac 1{n!}\int_0^z (z-t)^{n}\log\Gamma(t)\,dt$$

Answer (score 4):

This is purely guessing. For integer $n$, we seem to have something like
$$
\int_0^1 t^n\log\Gamma(t+a)dt = -n! \psi^{(-n-2)}(a)+n!\psi^{(-n-2)}(1+a)-\frac{n!}{1!}\psi^{(-n-1)}(1+a)+\frac{n!}{2!}\psi^{(-n)}(1+a)-\frac{n!}{3!}\psi^{(-n+1)}(1+a)+\frac{n!}{4!}\psi^{(-n+2)}(1+a)-\cdots
$$
so I suspect that 
$$
I(a,n)=\int_0^1 t^n\log\Gamma(t+a)dt = n!(-1)^{n+1}\left( \psi^{(-n-2)}(a) -\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\psi^{(-n-2+k)}(1+a) \right)
$$
this seems to work numerically for integer $n\ge 0$ and any $a$ I have tried. This gives some sort of closed forms, for example
$$
I(1,1) = -\frac{1}{4} - 2 \ln A + \psi^{(-3)}(1)\\
I(1,2) = \frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{2\pi}{A^4}\right)\\
$$
with $A$ the Glaisher–Kinkelin constant.

Comment: Yes that looks good to me.  Awhile after asking this question, I came across a semi-closed form in Henri Cohen's Number Theory Vol 2 (pg. 130).  It is essentially expressible in terms of the Hurwitz zeta function and it's derivative at negative integers.